# MinidumpWriteDump from managed code throws an AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, .net, interop, clr, minidump

I have the basic MiniDumpWriteDump method interop copied off the internet in my C# (3.5) project.

Up till now, i have used this code to register on the UnhandledException event, to take a crash dump before the process shuts down.

In a particular scenario i am facing now, i have set this function to be used in some other case, to take a diagnostic memory dump of the process.

Whenever this function gets called (not from the UnhandledException handler), it throws an *AccessViolationException*

Here's what the MiniDump code looks like (removed some redundant parts):

```
using (var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, 
                                         System.IO.FileMode.Create, 
                                         System.IO.FileAccess.Write, 
                                         System.IO.FileShare.None))
{
    MiniDumpExceptionInformation exp;
    exp.ThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
    exp.ClientPointers = false;
    exp.ExceptionPointers = Marshal.GetExceptionPointers();

    bool bRet = MiniDumpWriteDump(
                GetCurrentProcess(),
                GetCurrentProcessId(),
                fs.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle(),
                (uint)dumpType,
                ref exp,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                IntPtr.Zero);

    return bRet;
}
```

Native types are defined like so:

```
//typedef struct _MINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION {
        //    DWORD ThreadId;
        //    PEXCEPTION_POINTERS ExceptionPointers;
        //    BOOL ClientPointers;
        //} MINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION, *PMINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION;
        // Pack=4 is important! So it works also for x64!
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]  
        struct MiniDumpExceptionInformation
        {
            public uint ThreadId;
            public IntPtr ExceptionPointers;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public bool ClientPointers;
        }
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong.  Lots of stuff missing.

Comment: What is missing? This same code works perfectly well from the context of an unhandled exception handler, however in another case fails on exception. What else can i add to my original question to make it clearer?

Comment: Well, the access violation exception itself seems to be missing in action for starters. Could you include a stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Marshal.GetExceptionPointers() might return IntPtr.Zero (maybe when the OS sees the exception as handled). If this is the case you can try to put the call of 'MiniDumpWriteDump' somewhere else. I have had the same problem and solved it by putting 'MiniDumpWriteDump' into the event handler 'AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException'.